# Who has been buffed in BlazBlue: Continuum Shift?

Tags: blazblue-continuum-shift

After playing BlazBlue: Continuum Shift with a friend,I felt like many characters got a significant buff. This got me wondering, which characters have been buffed in the game compared to the original? In particular, one of my favorite characters, Bang, who was kind of weak in the original felt significantly buffed.

In my search for info most of the pages have gone into extreme technical detail. I'm more looking for something a more casual fan of the game may be able to understand. The more detailed answers though are not discouraged =)

Comment: Tagged as requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matchups are a lot more balanced overall. Tager is no longer completely helpless against characters like Lambda or Arakune, who were both "nerfed" a bit, not to mention Tager got a few really good moves like Gadget Finger (picks up an opponent off the ground after doing a 360 for example to allow Tager to initiate a guessing game) and a quick magnetizing move (Back-D). Unfortunately, Rachel got nerfed into bottom tier.

Hakumen, Bang, and Litchi are all near the top of the tier list when they previously weren't. Hakumen's standing and jumping pokes have absolutely insane reach now. Litchi has some of the longest combos in the game now other than Carl.

All the characters are more interesting to play, which is a "buff" in my opinion unless you're playing at the very top level. Playing Carl Clover actually requires a lot of creativity and ingenuity now instead of simply practicing the setup for his infinite clap loop.

It's definitely worth buying the sequel, it's such a massive improvement over the first game.

Comment: I was happy to read all of this answer except the part about Rachel getting nerfed to the bottom. Sadness ensued...